# Group Date by Date Range of 2 hours with multiple dates involved using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, data-structures, group-by

I have some entries that are somewhat like this:

```
StartDate: 03/24/2022 11:00 AM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 11:31 AM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f
StartDate: 03/24/2022 11:00 AM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 11:51 AM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f
StartDate: 03/24/2022 11:52 AM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 12:16 PM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f
StartDate: 03/24/2022 11:54 AM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 12:05 PM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f
StartDate: 03/24/2022 12:16 AM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 01:00 PM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f

StartDate: 03/24/2022 04:00 PM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 06:22 PM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f
StartDate: 03/24/2022 06:15 AM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 07:00 AM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f
StartDate: 03/24/2022 06:49 AM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 07:33 AM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f
```

These are all in one List.

I would like to group these entries into 2 entries using LINQ. Each of the entries should have earliest StartDate and latest EndDate, looking like this:

```
StartDate: 03/24/2022 11:00 AM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 01:00 PM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f

StartDate: 03/24/2022 04:00 PM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 07:33 AM, UserId: f5cfc94c-d252-4ead-8de7-4933995efb1f
```

Condition for separating these 2 entries within a list should be if the difference between StartDate - EndDate >= 01:59 (1 hour and 59 minutes).
Also, removing any possible duplicates before any further filtration is important.

I've managed to remove duplicates and get the Min Start and Max EndDate, but splitting into two entries is a problem. I could separate these into two lists with foreach, but I don't see how is it possible to do it via System.LINQ.

Edit:
Here's an example of what I've managed so far. I'm still missing the conditional two hour grouping.

```
var distinctLogs = sleepLogs
                .GroupBy(l => new
                {
                    l.StartDate.Date
                })
                .Select(group =>
                {
                    var minStartDate = group.OrderBy(entry => entry.StartDate).First().StartDate;
                    var maxEndDate = group.OrderByDescending(entry => entry.EndDate).First().EndDate;
                    return new SleepLog
                    {
                        EndDate = maxEndDate,
                        StartDate = minStartDate,
                        UserId = group.First().UserId,
                    };
                });
```

Comment: Why are you mandating use of LINQ?

Comment: It's not necessary to use LINQ, just I can't see it not getting extremely dirty without it. What I would like is the cleanest possible solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the field you use to sort these records?

Comment: Order is not important in this use case. If necessary, it should be ordered by ascending StartDate.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be of help?

For the purpose of keeping it small, I'll use a simplified version of your entry class that does not contain the `UserId` (as it is not addressed in your description of the grouping/filtering requirements) in this approach:

```csharp
public class SleepLog
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    
    public SleepLog(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        StartDate = start;
        EndDate = end;
    }
    
    public SleepLog Clone() => new(StartDate, EndDate);
}
```

Let's then say you have your input list `List<SleepLog> sleepLogs`, as well as an initially empty resulting list `List<SleepLog> distinctLogs`. I think you can achieve what you want by using a `foreach` loop without it getting 'extremely dirty'.

The logic goes as follows:

- We want to order `sleepLogs` by `StartDate`, so that the entries appear chronologically.

  - (I see in your example that you have done this slightly different than what is done here in this approach. The filtering could be customized if needed, but here's an explanation of what's done here anyways:)
  - If there's any chance that entries may have identical `StartDate` values, the entries in the input list could initially be filtered. The goal of the filtering is, for each distinct `StartDate` value, to only keep the one entry that covers the largest timespan.

    - This can be accomplished by first grouping the entries by `StartDate`, then selecting the one entry from each group that has the largest `EndDate` value.
- For each **entry** in `sleepLogs`, we will perform *exactly one* of the following three actions:

  1. add a new item with the **entry**'s property values to `distinctLogs`
  2. update the `EndDate` value of the last item in `distinctLogs` with the **entry**'s `EndDate` value (i.e. extending the latest existing distinct log)
  3. do nothing

Option 1 is applicable in two scenarios:

- when `distinctLogs` is empty (i.e. in the first iteration of the `foreach` loop)
- when the gap between the **entry**'s `StartDate` and the so-far latest existing distinct log's `EndDate` is at least two hours.

Option 2 is applicable if option 1 is not applicable *and* the **entry**'s `EndDate`is later than the so-far latest existing distinct log's `EndDate`.

Option 3 is applicable in all other cases.

It could be implemented as follows:

```csharp
int threshold = 2;
List<SleepLog> distinctLogs = new();

foreach (var log in sleepLogs
    .GroupBy(r => r.StartDate)
    .Select(gr => gr.MaxBy(r => r.EndDate))
    .OrderBy(r => r.StartDate))
{
    if (!distinctLogs.Any() ||
       (log.StartDate - distinctLogs.Last().EndDate).Hours >= threshold)
    {
        distinctLogs.Add(log.Clone());
    }
    else if (log.EndDate > distinctLogs.Last().EndDate)
    {
        distinctLogs.Last().EndDate = log.EndDate;
    }
}
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UGxbkS).

---

**Note:** Considering the example input and associated desired output you have provided, it seems to me that there are some AM/PM mix-ups. I am assuming the following changes are applicable:

Input:

> StartDate: 03/24/2022 12:16 <del>AM</del>, EndDate: 03/24/2022 01:00 PM
> StartDate: 03/24/2022 12:16 **PM**, EndDate: 03/24/2022 01:00 PM

> StartDate: 03/24/2022 06:15 <del>AM</del>, EndDate: 03/24/2022 07:00 <del>AM</del>
> StartDate: 03/24/2022 06:15 **PM**, EndDate: 03/24/2022 07:00 **PM**

> StartDate: 03/24/2022 06:49 <del>AM</del>, EndDate: 03/24/2022 07:33 <del>AM</del>
> StartDate: 03/24/2022 06:49 **PM**, EndDate: 03/24/2022 07:33 **PM**

Output:

> StartDate: 03/24/2022 04:00 PM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 07:33 <del>AM</del>
> StartDate: 03/24/2022 04:00 PM, EndDate: 03/24/2022 07:33 **PM**